# can I manually invoke supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow?

Tags: ios, orientation, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

In iOS8 `UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification` no longer exists and a solution for detecting an exit from a fullscreen youtube video is to set a notifier on `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification`

The thing is that `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` is too late to change the orientation, so I was wondering if I can manually invoke the method (in appdelegate)

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

Comment: Why are you changing the orientation? If YouTube is launching a new window, your application doesn't need to allow rotation for the YouTube video player to rotate.

Comment: it's inside my app. not a new window...

Comment: and trust me - it inherits the orientation from the app, and fullscreen video is the only think I want to allow in landscape

Comment: If `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` is fired, it's because there's a second window in your app...